# Remove specific screen resolutions in dropdown menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drop-down-menu

I am trying to remove some resolutions in my dropdown menu. I want to remove because I will not use it. This what I did (see code below),

What I tried:

```cs
resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
foreach(Resolution resolution in resolutions) {
    for (int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++) {
        if (resolutionDropdown.options[i].text == "320 x 200") {
            resolutionDropdown.options.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    resolutionDropdown.options.Add(new TMPro.TMP_Dropdown.OptionData(ResolutionToString(resolution)));
}
```

but I got this error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 
Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index  
System.Collections.Generic.List1[TMPro.TMP_Dropdown+OptionData].get_Item (Int32 index)  
 (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:633)   
SettingsManager.OnEnable ()  
 (at Assets/Scripts/Settings/SettingsManager.cs:38)
```

Comment: You have a loop in a loop, so you are removing item[i] multiple times form your totally unrelated resolutiondropdownthingee. You would see quite quickly what is going on by simply stepping through this in debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
  resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
  foreach (Resolution resolution in resolutions) 
  {           
     if (ResolutionToString(resolution) != "320 x 200") 
             resolutionDropdown.options.Add(new TMPro.TMP_Dropdown.OptionData(ResolutionToString(resolution)));
  }
```

Comment: @jonmrich , what link are you talking about? I gave the answer??

Comment: Code only answers really aren't that helpful and generally get marked like this. Not sure how it got marked "link only" though.